# Proof that cardinality of the union of disjoints sets is the sum of cardinality of each set

Tags: real-analysis

Bartle, [*Introduction to Real Analysis* (2011 4 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471433314), 1.3.4 Theorem p 17.

> 1.3.4 Theorem (a) If A is a set with m elements and B is a set with n elements and if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ , then $A \cup B$ has m + n elements.
> (b) If A is a set with $m \in \mathbb{N}$ elements and $C \subseteq A$ is a set with 1 element, then $A\C$ is a set with m - 1 elements.
> (c) If C is an infinite set and B is a finite set, then $C\B$ is an infinite set.

[image: book proof]

> The proofs of parts (b) and (c) are left to the reader, see Exercise 2. Q.E.D

1. Why do we define $g$ to be a function of $i-m$?
2. How to finish the proof?

Comment: @bof it represents a set of natural numbers that contains m elements. sorry, i assumed this was common notation. Book title has been added to the original question, thank you.

Comment: If $$\{f(1),f(2),\dots,f(m)\}=A$$ and $$\{g(1),g(2),\dots,g(n)\}=B,$$ and if we want $$\{h(1),h(2),\dots,h(m+n)\}=A\cup B,$$ it seems a most reasonable plan to define $h$ so that $$\{h(1),h(2),\dots,h(m)\}=\{f(1),f(2),\dots,f(m)\}=A$$ and $$\{h(m+1),h(m+2),\dots,h(m+n)\}=\{g(1),g(2),\dots,g(n)\}=B.$$ And the obvious way to do that is to set $$h(1)=f(1),\ h(2)=f(2),\ \dots,\ h(m)=f(m)$$ and $$h(m+1)=g(1),\ h(m+2)=g(2),\ \dots,h(m+n)=g(n);$$ in other words, $$h(i)=f(i)\text{ for }1\le i\le m$$ and $$h(i)=g(i-m)\text{ for }m+1\le i\le m+n.$$

Comment: @bof you're totally right, thank you for clarifying, It seems i just overlooked that. I'm still not sure how to pursue the proof the bijection onto the union.

Comment: You have to use what you're given: (i) $f:\mathbb Z_m\to A$ is a bijection; (ii) $g:\mathbb Z_n\to B$ is a bijection; (iii) the definition of $h;$ and (iv) $A\cap B=\emptyset.$ You have to prove that $h$ is (a) surjective and (b) injective. Which part are you stuck on?